# TR element .display=none|hidden rendering in IE9+

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHh3s/10/)

Can anyone explain how this can be handled in IE8 and before as well as IE 9 and after, CONSISTENTLY?

Depending on your browser, you will get different results when you click the hide button, then click the show button.

IE8 and earlier, hide and restore the row correctly (or at least, as I want it).  IE9+ and Chrome, once the row is hidden, restoring it dumps ALL the columns into the FIRST column, and looses it's formatting.  The remaining columns are then blank.

Compatibility view works in some cases, but I'd rather not resort to CV if possible.

Any tips?

```
CODE SAMPLE?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table rows are set to `display: table-row;` by default, so switching to inline will ruin the formatting. Replace inline with table-row.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
document.getElementById("tr2").style.display = "table-row";
document.getElementById("tr3").style.display = "table-row";
```

inside `showButton()` method since the default `display` property of `tr` is `table-row`.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHh3s/13/)**

Answer (score 1):

Change `inline` to `table-row` in the show code

The issue is that the width won't be adjusted to the others in any other display type